# tmux bash konsole change title

Tags: bash, tmux

How can I configurate bash or tmux for make konsole change window title?

If I run tmux from xterm, it changes title
But from konsole not change

I also have some tricks in bashrc

```
# window title
if [ "$SHELL" = '/bin/bash' ] && [ ! -z "$KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION" ]
then
  case $TERM in
     rxvt|*term)
        trap 'qdbus org.kde.konsole $KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION org.kde.konsole.Session.setTitle 1 $HOSTNAME\ :\ $BASH_COMMAND' DEBUG
     ;;
  esac
fi
```

And after this title is changed manually from bash, but if run tmux it not changed again!

[trap](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_12_02.html)

**Update**: thing that i need is a `%w` modificator in window title for konsole.
**Solved**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing that i need is a %w modificator in window title for konsole.